# Is There a "Predefined Exception" for Handling ArrayOutOfBounds Indexing Errors in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch, indexoutofboundsexception

With this `divideByZero()` function, It errors out and triggers the catch method:

```js
function divideByZero() {
    return 1/0;
};


try {
  divideByZero();
  echo "i dont run";
} catch ( DivisionByZeroError $err) {
  echo $err;  //"DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero in C"
}
```

Which is exactly what I want, but I can only get this message by using PHP's `DivisionByZeroError` "Predefined Exception".

Now, I am wondering how I can get this same functionality with this `arrayOutOfBounds()` function:

```js
function arrayOutOfBounds() {
   $arr = ["", "", ""];
   return $arr[3]; //index doesnt exist.
};

try {
 arrayOutOfBounds();
 echo "I still run, even though the arrayOutOfBounds function has a problem";
} catch (Error $err) { // <-- is the issue here?
  echo $err; //I dont run.
};
```

With the second `arrayOutOfBounds()` function, It doesn't `catch` the error, It completes the rest of the code in the `try` block, but also automatically `echo`'s "Warning: Undefined array key 3 in C:\Users on line #".

I would simply like for this `arrayOutOfBounds()` function to catch the index error, not run the rest of the code in the `try` block, and `echo` the correct `$err` message.

I've looked through the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php) and tried them all.

Comment: You can not catch an exception, when none gets thrown to begin with. Accessing a non-existing array element simply doesn't.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for correcting my misunderstanding, is there a way I can check if this is an indexing error within the `arrayOutOfBounds()` function, and throw an error that will catch in the try block?

Comment: I am currently reading into this exception: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.outofboundsexception.php

Comment: It might be that some of the other SPL functions/classes throw that kind of exception, but just simple array access doesn't. All the examples in the comments on that page are _actively_ throwing an exception of this type themselves.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, I guess I will have to throw it manually. Ill post my solution, but I'm still open to an automatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, but here is a manual solution. The error is not automatically generated such as in the `divideByZero()` function, so I threw an error manually.

```js
function arrayOutOfBounds() {
  $arr = ["", "", ""];
  if (isset($arr[3])) {} else {
    throw new OutOfBoundsException("Index was outside the bounds of the array.");
  }
};

try {
  arrayOutOfBounds();
  echo "test"; //i dont run anymore
} catch (OutOfBoundsException $err) {
  echo $err; //i echo the $err message
};
```

Comment: `if ($arr[3])` will still create an `Undefined array key`/`Undefined offset` warning/notice, if you wanted to prevent that from showing as well, you should test if the element exists using `isset`.